# How Do I Create Expand All and Collapse All Links Outside of the jQuery Treeview Plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, treeview

The [jQuery Treeview Plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-treeview/) adds Collapse All, Expand All and Toggle All links to the "treeviewcontrol" div when the control property is defined as follows:

```
$("#black, #gray").treeview({
   control: "#treecontrol",
   persist: "cookie",
   cookieId: "treeview-black"
});
```

This works great, but I'd like the ability to expand and collapse the treeview from other page elements outside of the treeview itself. I've looked at the source, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check out the demo page here you can see there is a div#treecontrol, well just make it a `treecontrol` class:

```
<div class="treecontrol">
 <a title="Collapse the entire tree below" href="#"><img src="../images/minus.gif" /> Collapse All</a>
 <a title="Expand the entire tree below" href="#"><img src="../images/plus.gif" /> Expand All</a>
 <a title="Toggle the tree below, opening closed branches, closing open branches" href="#">Toggle All</a>
</div>
```

Then you can make as many copies of this control and put them anywhere you want. Don't forget to modify the control parameter:

```
$("#tree").treeview({ control: ".treecontrol" })
```

Comment: Clever idea, fudgey. That worked great and it answered my question so I'm accepting your answer.  For completeness, I needed a little more flexibility in the link layout. I ended up triggering the treecontrol links from links outside of the treecontrol. In other words, to collapse all link A's click event did this: $('#treecontrol a:eq(0)').click(); And since I didn't need the treecontrol links to be clicked on directly, I hide those links when the document first loads up: $('#treecontrol a').hide();  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(".treeview").treeview({  // ".treeview" is your selector
  control: "#treecontrol", // this is your controller
  persist: "cookie",
  cookieId: "treeview-black"
});
```

That will close every single list with class "treeview" every time you click the "Collapse All" under the div#treecontrol.

Comment: I'm able to get the treecontrol to work fine. I would like to trigger expand all from outside of the treecontrol though.