# jQuery treeView plugin collapse/expand all

Tags: jquery

I Would like to have two buttons on my site. Expand All, collapse All

Im using treeView jquery plugin: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/treeview

I cant find solution for doing that :/

Also while im generating ul li list dynamically on aspx server side code I would like do determine accorgind to queryString parameter which node should be expanded while others closed. I tried adding to each one class closed while to given one none but it didnt work :/

How can I say which node should be expanded ?

Thanks for any help, bye

Comment: possible duplicate of [How Do I Create Expand All and Collapse All Links Outside of the jQuery Treeview Plugin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603653/how-do-i-create-expand-all-and-collapse-all-links-outside-of-the-jquery-treeview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the [demo's](http://jquery.bassistance.de/treeview/demo/) you should see exactly what you need for example 4.

Add the following to your page:

```
<div id="treecontrol">
    <a title="Collapse the entire tree below" href="#"><img src="../images/minus.gif" /> Collapse All</a>
    <a title="Expand the entire tree below" href="#"><img src="../images/plus.gif" /> Expand All</a>
    <a title="Toggle the tree below, opening closed branches, closing open branches" href="#">Toggle All</a>
</div>
```

And when you wire up your tree control specify the 'treecontrol'

```
$("#black, #gray").treeview({
  control: "#treecontrol"
});
```

**Be warned**
The order of your anchor tags is important in your control as the plugin uses `.eq()` to assign the appropriate functions.

```
$("a:eq(0)", control).click(handler(CLASSES.collapsable));
// click on second to expand tree
$("a:eq(1)", control).click(handler(CLASSES.expandable));
// click on third to toggle tree
$("a:eq(2)", control).click(handler());
```

Comment: The link provided is dead.